# XML data pasing

Tags: ajax, xml

Hi I am trying to display data from XML file to unordered list. Any help would be great. I do have an XML file books data wherein trying to print or display the books author etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>
<script>

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      report(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
    function report(xml){
        var i;
        var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        var table = "";
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("CD");
        for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){

            table+="<li>" + x[i].getElementByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</li>";

        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
<body>
<ul id="demo"></ul>
<button type="submit" onclick="loadDoc()">RUUUUNNNNN</button>

</body>
</html>
```